# Is it possible to draw a .pbf from an ArcGIS Feature Server

Tags: openlayers

I'm unable to draw an ArcGIS FeatureServer .pbf result in OpenLayers 6.4.3. The request completes successfully but nothing appears. The layer in question is the NFIS Fire Perimeter Layer.
`https://services3.arcgis.com/T4QMspbfLg3qTGWY/arcgis/rest/services/Public_Wildfire_Perimeters_View/FeatureServer/0`

My code looks like this...

```
    let url = "https://services3.arcgis.com/T4QMspbfLg3qTGWY/arcgis/rest/services/Public_Wildfire_Perimeters_View/FeatureServer/0"
    let extent = this.props.extent;
    let urlFormatted =
      url +
      `/query?f=pbf&returnGeometry=true&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&` +
      `geometry={"xmin":${extent[0]},"ymin":${extent[1]},"xmax":${extent[2]},"ymax":${
        extent[3]
      },"spatialReference":{"wkid":102100}}&` +
      `geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=102100&outFields=*&outSR=102100&resultType=tile`;

    this.vectorSource = new VectorTileSource({
      format: new MVT(),
      url: urlFormatted
    });

    /**
     * The layer hosting the source vector.
     */

    this.vectorLayer = new VectorTileLayer({
      id: this.props.id,
      visible: true,
      source: this.vectorSource,
      zIndex: 200
    });

    this.props.map.getLayers().push(this.vectorLayer);
```

Comment: VectorTile sources/layers require a tile grid, so you would need to set a single tile, single zoom level grid for your extent.  It might be better to read the data into a standard vector layer.  To do that Feature class must be specified as Feature (not the default RenderFeature) and readFeatures requires the tile extent as an option.  For example https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-bell-6skr7?file=/main.js

Comment: Hi @Dylan, did you ever resolve your issue? If so, could you share the solution. I'm in the same boat and haven't seen an example demonstrating this whereby xmin, ymin, xmax and ymax are used for tiles instead of {z}/{x}/{y}.