# Using ArcGIS Online PBF from FeatureServer in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, arcgis-online, vector-tiles, feature-service, pbf

I'm looking for a way to use the PBF format from an ArcGIS Online FeatureServer in Leaflet.

There are lots of examples using L.vectorGrid.protobuf with URLs for PBF tiles structured like {z}/{x}/{y}.pbf but as I'm hoping to use a FeatureServer to accesses this data, these examples will not work for me.

I haven't found an example of how to do this and am hoping you can help. Here's the [Esri Map using PBF from a FeatureServer](https://csurams.maps.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?url=https://services1.arcgis.com/KNdRU5cN6ENqCTjk/ArcGIS/rest/services/Wells_NM_RG/FeatureServer/0&source=sd) I'm hoping to use. And here's an [example API call from the Esri Map using PBF](https://services1.arcgis.com/KNdRU5cN6ENqCTjk/ArcGIS/rest/services/Wells_NM_RG/FeatureServer/0/query?f=pbf&returnGeometry=true&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&geometry=%7B%22xmin%22%3A-12056871.093590401%2C%22ymin%22%3A3832246.850107581%2C%22xmax%22%3A-11972484.614363587%2C%22ymax%22%3A3916633.3293343927%2C%22spatialReference%22%3A%7B%22wkid%22%3A102100%2C%22latestWkid%22%3A3857%7D%7D&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=102100&outFields=*&returnCentroid=false&returnExceededLimitFeatures=false&maxRecordCountFactor=3&outSR=102100&resultType=tile&quantizationParameters=%7B%22mode%22%3A%22view%22%2C%22originPosition%22%3A%22upperLeft%22%2C%22tolerance%22%3A152.87405657031263%2C%22extent%22%3A%7B%22xmin%22%3A-12053813.612458995%2C%22ymin%22%3A3835304.331238987%2C%22xmax%22%3A-11975542.095494995%2C%22ymax%22%3A3913575.848202987%2C%22spatialReference%22%3A%7B%22wkid%22%3A102100%2C%22latestWkid%22%3A3857%7D%7D%7D)

How can I address this challenge?

Comment: like this? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/348158/styling-polygons-in-a-map-tile-pbf-file-in-leaflet

Comment: There seems to be no such plugin/library for Leaflet, but is' easily doable in native OpenLayers.

Comment: Thanks @TomazicM. I've started looking through OpenLayers posts related to this and came across [another open question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/374055/is-it-possible-to-draw-a-pbf-from-an-arcgis-feature-server) from September. Do you know of an OpenLayers example where the xmin, ymin, xmax and ymax are used for pbf instead of {z}/{x}/{y}?

Comment: Yes, see example from Mike's comment on the mentioned question: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-bell-6skr7?file=/main.js. It's really not an open question, since half of the Mike's answers are given in comments.

Comment: Hi @TomazicM, I did see @Mike's comment but their response doesn't use xmin, ymin, xmax and ymax extents when requesting the pbf tile. Do you know of an example where the extent is used for displaying a pbf tile (i.e. constructed similar to @Dylan's initial question <code>`/query?f=pbf&returnGeometry=true&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&` +
      `geometry={"xmin":${extent[0]},"ymin":${extent[1]},"xmax":${extent[2]},"ymax":${
        extent[3]</code>) Thanks for your continued support.

Comment: Some new info after some research: no matter what I tried (within OpenLayers, with MapBox geobuf library or online converter https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/pbf-to-geojson) , I could not decode pbf data from above mentioned service. But I had no problem using service when I replaced format `f=pbf` with `f=geojson`.

Comment: Hi @TomazicM, Thanks so much for digging further into this. I ended-up extending the Leaflet.VectorGrid.Protobuf.js library to include support for xmin, ymin, xmax, and ymax in the service URL by adding <code>_getVectorTilePromise: function(coords, tileBounds) {


     var b = this._tileCoordsToBounds(coords);

  var data = {
   s: this._getSubdomain(coords),
   x: coords.x,
   y: coords.y,
   z: coords.z,

   xmin:b._southWest.lng,
   ymin:b._southWest.lat,
   xmax:b._northEast.lng,
   ymax:b._northEast.lat

  } ...</code> But the new VectorTile( pbf ) is empty :( like you saw

Comment: I'm now looking into the converter you provided as [the service](https://services1.arcgis.com/KNdRU5cN6ENqCTjk/ArcGIS/rest/services/Wells_NM_RG/FeatureServer/0/query?f=pbf&returnGeometry=true&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&geometry={"xmin":-11861192.3011804,"ymin":4190583.6387083936,"xmax":-11818999.061566994,"ymax":4232776.878321799,"spatialReference":{"wkid":102100,"latestWkid":3857}}&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=102100&outFields=*&returnCentroid=false&returnExceededLimitFeatures=true&maxRecordCountFactor=3&outSR=4326&resultType=tile') has data that ESRI is able to display.

Comment: The [converter](mygeodata.cloud/converter/pbf-to-geojson) you shared @TomazicM is great except for the size limit of "5 MB of Converted Data / month". Like you noted, it is doesn't work with the ESRI pbf data I have. This is likely because the pbf spec from ESRI's query service is their own version. Here a link to the git repo for is spec [https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-pbf](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-pbf) and the [thread](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-api-for-javascript/protocolbuffer-binary-format-pbf-documentation-or-examples/td-p/464691) I found this from.

Comment: Now that they have finally published specs, maybe there will be some ESRI pbf JS decoder in the future.

Comment: It looks like there's a decoder method in the FeatureCollection class ([https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-pbf/tree/main/proto/FeatureCollection/parsers/js](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-pbf/tree/main/proto/FeatureCollection/parsers/js)) so I think all the pieces are there. I'll see if I can get a working example together. Thanks so much for your input on this @TomazicM.

Answer (score 0):

Reference:

https://transparentgov.net/cleargov1/940/pbf-not-work-with-mapserver-but-work-with-featureserver

For example, arcgis REST api, FeatureServer only,  you can use http URL like

```
      '...?f=pbf'
```

instead of

```
      '...?f=json',
```

you will get a single piece of response from .xhr,

you can use mapbox pbf to unzip pbf back to json.

Here is a tool to convert ESRI pbf format into json

https://github.com/rowanwins/arcgis-pbf-parser

Here is ESRI pbf format

https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-pbf/tree/main/proto/FeatureCollection

Here is a library for retrieving features from an ArcGIS FeatureServer or MapServer. This library makes tiled requests rather than simply requesting every feature.

https://github.com/rowanwins/mapbox-gl-arcgis-featureserver